# Robust web Socket Streaming to Kafka in Java

Tags: java, sockets, apache-kafka, java-websocket

I need to record from an unreliable web socket connection and stream into Kafka. 
Our Kafka cluster is pretty reliable and we can make it highly available.

What is the best approach to make the web socket connection as reliable as possible? I would like to minimize data loss.

One solution would be to have multiple processes or web socket clients listening and streaming to multiple Kafka topics. Then do a filter with Kafka streams. This only works if each message that I obtain has a unique id, which is not always the case.

Another solution would be to monitor the web socket connection and restart or reset it. But then I might have data loss. Or rely on web socket heartbeats?
Or code my own error handlers?

What frameworks / libraries from the Java are in this space to do the best job? Currently, I use the web socket client from org.java-websocket.

I think this is a pretty standard use case in web socket and also in Kafka producer development, so I am sure I do not need to reinvent the wheel.